# Starting mysql if it is not started

Tags: mysql, linux, service, centos

Once a day, I restart my mysql by cron. Some times, the service hangs up and can not start. So, I need to check if mysql is running (smth. like: service mysqld status) and start mysqld if it is not running. Can somebody advice a simple script for this action?

Answer (score 4):

EASY ANSWER: Instead of using a bash **script**, you could use a single command and add it to the cron jobs.

```
* * * * * systemctl is-active --quiet mysqld || systemctl restart mysqld
```

DETAILED ANSWER:

If MySQL is dropping out, it may be a problem with your server configuration (Apache | nginx) or MySQL configuration. DOS attacks or system processes may cause a spike in system resource usages (see image).  The end result is that MySQL process gets shutdown by the Kernel.  For a long-term solution should look at optimizing your Apache or MySQL configurations.

[image: System resources spike causing RAM spike (just before 6pm) and system resources spike causing only a CPU spike Midnight on Tue 18]

There are several other discussions Stack Overflow those topics as well as the MySQL manual and Percona Blog:

MySQL Manual - How MySQL Uses Memory:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-use.html

Percona Server: Improve Scalability with Percona Thread Pool

https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/28/10-mysql-performance-tuning-settings-after-installation/

Percona - Best Practices for Configuring Optimal MySQL Memory Usage:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/03/best-practices-for-configuring-optimal-mysql-memory-usage/

How to Optimize MySQL Performance Using MySQLTuner:

https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/how-to-optimize-mysql-performance-using-mysqltuner/

Apache Memory Usage Configuration:

https://serverfault.com/questions/254436/apache-memory-usage-optimization

Apache Manual on Performance Tuning:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/perf-tuning.html

Tuning Apache Server:

https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/apache-tips-and-tricks/tuning-your-apache-server/

However, with respect to your original question, yes, you can script a temporary solution that checks if MySQL service is loaded and active and will restart MySQL if it is not loaded and active.

You did not mention what operating system you are using. That would help to give you a specific command.  I will give you an example for CentOS linux.
Look at the following output of the command `systemctl status mysql`.  You can see at the top that the service is **loaded** and **active**.

```
[root@centos-mysql-demo ~]# systemctl status mysqld
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-06-18 18:28:18 UTC; 924ms ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 3350 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3273 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3353 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
           └─3353 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Jun 18 18:28:11 centos-mysql-demo systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Jun 18 18:28:18 centos-mysql-demo systemd[1]: Started MySQL Server.
```

If the service is not loaded, then a command such as:

```
systemctl status mysqld || systemctl restart mysqld
```

will do the trick of re-starting the process.  You **could** cron that:

```
* * * * * systemctl status mysqld || systemctl restart mysqld
```

However, in the case that mysql is **loaded**, but the service is not **active**, your cron will do nothing.  So, you should use a more detailed command such as:

`* * * * * systemctl is-active --quiet mysqld || systemctl restart mysqld`

In this case, if the service is **loaded** but **inactive** such as the state that a DOS attack can leave your mysql service, the command will also restart mysql.  Using the `--quiet` flag just specifies the command only to return a status code, not output anything to the screen.  If you ommit the `--quiet` flag you will see a status output of either `active` or `inactive`.

You may also create some swap space to add more available RAM resources to your server, although both Apache and MySQL manuals specify that you do not want those applications to require swap space.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile count=2096 bs=1MiB
chmod 600 /swapfile
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
swapon --show
swapon --summary
free -h
```

Comment: I've added some details about the situation in general as well as why this answer is better than the other posted answer.

Comment: Why downvotes?  The ultimate goal of the OP should perhaps be to configure MySQL properly for his server configuration / bandwidth load, but I answered his question.  In the meantime of proper configuration, this method will get you by from your database dropping out.

Answer (score 1):

First create a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
UP=$(service mysql status|awk '{ print $1}');
if [ "$UP" != 'SUCCESS!' ];
then
        echo "MySQL is down.";
        sudo service mysql start

else
        echo "All is well.";
fi
```

Second add a crontab for running every 3 minute

```
*/3 * * * * /home/user/scripts/monitor.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

NOTE: This solution must be edited acording yor distro (service, /etc/init.d/ systemctl, mysql, mysqld)

**Original answer (I think taht use Cpanel because tag cpanel it's on post)**

Cpanel allows you to control certain services, and add other easily through chksrvd. Mysql For this you just have to configure it.

**Home >> Service Configuration >> Service Manager**

Alli can configure MySQL for this monitored and if they attempt to lift fall by the system.

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/TailWatch

It would be desirable to revise the MySQL log that is in /var/lib/mysql/.err generalemnte

Comment: I do not use cpanel, so I need a simple script to add it to crontab.

Comment: I edit my response. I apologize for first response. I searh unswered questions for cpanel and you question are on results. I thin that a Cpanel question.